# Why are the quads on this imported obj refusing to show smooth when looking from the right?

Tags: materials, import, normals, obj

I have imported a model from turbosquid as an obj and set up the normal and the opacity that was included with the model and the UVs seem to work fine. For some reason every quad is showing as a try and does not want to smooth out after trying Recalculate outside, average normals by face, or smooth normals modifier. It only seems to appear when looking at it from the right side (image 1), when looking at the left side it looks great (image 2).

Did I import the model incorrectly in some way to cause this? Why is the problem only visible from one angle?

I am sure I have seen something similar to this asked before but I can not find an example now that I am looking for it, sorry in advance.

Edit: also have tried subdividing (issue persists but smaller tris visible), tried smoothing faces/edges after turning all quads to tris (no visible effect)

Edit2: I think I may have narrowed it down, I unplugged the normal and the issue is gone, but I really do want to use the normal map.(image 4) There are no triangle shapes in the normal image, so does this mean the issue is with the UV map somewhere?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you checked if there is *Object Data Properties > Geometry Data > Custom Split Normals Data*?

Comment: Thank you. I saw that it was there, yes. This could be from all the smoothing attempts and setting from faces that I have been doing. Regardless, I cleared it and tried turning all quads to tris and smoothing all edges/faces/set from faces. Not much changes other than on a few faces near the top but they still look bad when looking from the right

Comment: I think I may have narrowed it down, I unplugged the normal and the issue is gone, but I really do want to use the normal map.(image 4) There are no triangle shapes in the normal image, so does this mean the issue is with the UV map somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the normal image color space to raw, it was sRGB. I think this fixed it:

[image]